# Printing a matrix without for loops

Tags: c, string, matrix, printing, puts

I'm trying to print a char matrix using a single puts instead of nested loops, but I always get one more character in the end of the printing. I'm going to make a pong game, and I need to update the screen as fast as possible.

```
void main()
{
    int x, y;
    char map[40][80];

    for(y=0; y<40; y++)
    {
        for(x=0; x<80; x++)
        {
            map[y][x]='o';    //Just for testing.
        }
    }
    puts(map);
}
```

The last two lines printed with this code are:

```
ooooooooooooo...o (80 'o's)
<
```

Comment: Yes, I typed wrong. mapa is actually map. The language is C.

Comment: strings need to be null-terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x, y;
    char map[40*80+1];

    for(y=0; y<40; y++) {
        for(x=0; x<80; x++) {
            map[y*80+x]='o';
        }
    }
    map[40*80] = '\0';
    puts(map);

    return 0;
}
```

I've change the map to a linear array. This way it's easier to add a `\0` at the end to close the string. Without the `\0`, the `puts()` command doesn't know when to stop printing. In your case it was just a `<`, but it could have resulted in printing a lot of characters!

Also, I wouldn't rely on the fact that a multi-dimensional array maps linearly in memory.

Comment: "I wouldn't rely on the fact that a ...": You are right in general, but for a char-array this is guaranteed by the standard. `sizeof(char) is defined to be 1. Notet that it does not impliy CHAR_BIT == 8. Also, it might be suitable to terminate each line by newline to get a rectangular output, independent on the console-dimensions..

Comment: The dimensions should be #defines. They are very likely required later in the code, so there is ne need to have them everywhere and a clear name increases readbility massively.

Comment: @Olaf Terminating each line might just not be what the OP needs: He might be preparing to send the string to an LCD display or so. And I agree with, and very much support the use of #defines, this was not a style question.

Comment: That's why I did not state to terminate each line, but that it "might be suitable". Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesm't that signify an option or something to think about? Even an LCD driver would have to interpret the string (at least for NUL) and there is no tag for embedded or so, so it is at least open whether newline would be interpreted or not. Note that there is no LCD (btw: "Liquid Crystal Display display"?) that size out which does not have either graphics (with a font-renderer) or does interpret at least some basic control characters ("intelligent display") or even ANSI-sequences.

Comment: Regarding #defines: Right, it was not, but the questions was such as there is not much experience and I think it is actually god style to include some good programming style into an answer to help improve code quality (even more as the TO also spread literals). However, I should have tagged this comment as a sidenote, sorry I fforgot that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fwrite(3)` (or `write(2)` if you don't want the buffering, but you probably do if you are clearing the screen in the same write).

```
fwrite(map, 80, 40, stdout); // or any two numbers whose product is 80*40
```

or

```
write(1, map, 80*40);
```